# Java for loop multiple variables

Tags: java

I'm not sure why my Java code wont compile, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
   String rank = card.substring(0,1);
    String suit = card.substring(1);
    String cards = "A23456789TJQKDHSCl";
    String[] name = {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades","Clubs"};
    String c ="";
    for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length-1; b=a+1; a++;){
        if(rank===cards.substring(a,b){
            c+=name[a];
        }


    }
    system.out.println(c);
```

Comment: `system` must be capitalized: `System`

Comment: Remove the last two semi-colons from the for loop, and place a comma between `b = a + 1` and `a++`.

Comment: There is no `===` operator in Java, only `==`. (I assume you're coming from JavaScript?) Also, you're missing a `)` at the end of your `if`. Just go through the compiler errors one by one, they are very descriptive and help you fix these problems yourself.

Comment: Whenever you encounter a problem like this and ask it here, don't forget to include the complete error message.

Comment: Not everything in Java should be represented as a String. Consider using enums and making a Card class.

Comment: When your code won't compile, you get compiler errors letting you know why it won't compile. Specific with line number and reason.

Comment: @Tzafrir if error_reporting is set to display the error

Answer (score 30):

1. It is `cards.length()`, not `cards.length` (`length` is a **method** of `java.lang.String`, not an **attribute**).
2. It is `System.out` (capital 's'), not `system.out`. See [java.lang.System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).
3. It is

   ```
   for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length()-1; b=a+1, a++){
   ```

   not

   ```
   for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length-1; b=a+1; a++;){
   ```
4. Syntactically, it is `if(rank == cards.substring(a,b)){`, not `if(rank===cards.substring(a,b){` (double equals, not triple equals; missing closing parenthesis), but to compare if two Strings are equal you need to use `equals()`: `if(rank.equals(cards.substring(a,b))){`

You should probably consider downloading [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr1), which is an integrated development environment (not only) for Java development. Eclipse shows you the errors while you type and also provides help in fixing these. This makes it much easier to get started with Java development.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of this :
`for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length-1; b=a+1; a++;){`

It should be

```
for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length()-1; b=a+1, a++){
                                     ^         ^    ^  
                                     |         |    |  
                                     |         |    |  
            -------------------------------------------Note the changes
           |                    
           v                                                  |
   if(rank==cards.substring(a,b){                             |
-------------------------------------------------------------                                  
|
v
System.out.println(c); //capital S in system
```

Answer (score 7):

Only two Semicolons are allowed to be used in `for` loop.

1. Before first semicolon is the initialization part.
2. After first semicolon and before second semicolon is condition part (must result in boolean).
3. After second semicolon is variable manipulation part (increment/decrement part).

If you have do initialization of multiple variables or manipulation of multiple variables, you can achieve it by separating them with comma(,).

```
for(int i=0, j=5; i < 5; i++, j--)
```

NOTE: Multiple conditions separated by comma are NOT allowed.

```
for(int i=0, j=5; i < 5, j > 5; i++, j--) // This is NOT allowed.
```

Comment: It's worth noting that a condition like `i < 5 && j > 5` is perfectly legal, however.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is wrong. Try :

```
for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length()-1; b=a+1, a++){
```

Also, `System` instead of `system` and `==` instead of `===`.

But I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
    String rank = card.substring(0,1);
    String suit = card.substring(1);
    String cards = "A23456789TJQKDHSCl";

    String[] name = {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades","Clubs"};
    String c ="";
    for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length()-1; b=a+1, a++ )
    {
        if( rank.equals( cards.substring(a,b) ) )
        {
            c+=name[a];
        }


    }
    System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop can only contain three parameters, you have used 4. Please restate the question, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you every one. Allot of people commented and every one had a good suggestion. I swear I sat here for 45 minutes at school trying to figure out why it wouldn't let my for loop go. My AP teacher got a promotion so the Algebra 2 teachers took over our class... he has no clue on how to teach this stuff. Thank you all for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Separate the increments with a comma too.

```
for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length-1; b=a+1, a++)
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length-1; b=a+1; a++;){
```

to

```
for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length-1, b=a+1; a++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is malformed — it can't take 4 arguments, and you can't combine two with `;` as you did.

Use:

```
for(int a = 0, b = 1; a<cards.length-1; a++)
```