# for-loop with 2 variables?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm a student, and I need a little help, with the for loop. I know how to do it with one variable, but I have been asked to do it with two. The code is very simple, is just an example. The problem is that it doesn't compile, throwing various errors, like  expected, starting in line 3. I searched how to do it, but I can´t find any difference between this code and the one I found.
I just need a "tutorial", a simple explanation.

```
public class ABA {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for(int i = 0, int j = 0; i < 10; i++, j +2) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question and give us the first 10 errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java for loop multiple variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752536/java-for-loop-multiple-variables)

Comment: I understand where you are coming from @sstan , but I didn't realize it was a duplicate until I Googled "multiple values in for loop java", and was give a number of answers. It was only then I saw it was a duplicate, and marked as such.

Comment: Too add on good answers from @Watermel0n and @GC_ , I think this format is clearer and more readable:                                                                                                                        `int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(j);
            j += 2;
        }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update your for loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++, j += 2) {
    System.out.println("i -> " + i);
    System.out.println("j -> " + j);
}
```

**Output:**

```
i -> 0
j -> 0
i -> 1
j -> 2
i -> 2
j -> 4
i -> 3
j -> 6
i -> 4
j -> 8
i -> 5
j -> 10
i -> 6
j -> 12
i -> 7
j -> 14
i -> 8
j -> 16
i -> 9
j -> 18
```

- println has been modified slightly to reflect which is i and which is j
- use `j += 2` instead of `j + 2` to increment j
- i & j should be declared as `int i = 0, j = 0;`

Comment: Thanks, that indeeds works. The problem is that i don´t understand the error yet, because I changed the original code with the  j +=2 but it stills can´t compile. Thank you anyway, really appreciated.

Comment: Have you changed `int i = 0, int j = 0;` to `int i = 0, j = 0;`? The for loop that I have provided can definitely be compiled, and gives you the output shown in the answer.

Comment: I just realised you didn´t declare the type of the variable j and that was the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: @n697q Yup, that was it. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Two things wrong.
No need for second int, and j+2 should probably be j+=2 or j=j+2

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++, j+=2) {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```