# For loop with 2 variables?

Tags: java, loops, variables, for-loop

```
for (int xGreenBottles = 11, xyGreenBottles = 10; xGreenBottles > 0; xGreenBottles --, xyGreenBottles > 0, xyGreenBottles--)

   if (xGreenBottles == 0 && xyGreenBottles == 0)
   {

    System.out.println(xGreenBottles + " green bottles standing on the wall, " + xGreenBottles + "  green bottles standing on the wall, And if 1 green bottle should accidently fall, there'll be " + xyGreenBottles + " green bottles standing on the wall.");
     }

       else {
       System.out.println("There’ll be no green bottles standing on the wall.");
       }
```

Tried a billion different things but nothing has worked so far. If it is no where near anything coherent it's probably because i've been trying to do this for the last 4 hours and my brains fried. Sorry if the long system.out.println is awkward to read.

Also - it needs to use 2 variables.

**edit**

Alright sorry I didn't make it clear - I wasn't sure how to make the 'for' have 2 variables as it'd keep giving me an error. Mostly gave me 'not an expression' and was wondering on how to fix it.

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: What's the problem and what's the question?

Comment: `for (int xGreenBottles = 11, xyGreenBottles = 10; xGreenBottles > 0 && xyGreenBottles > 0; xGreenBottles --, xyGreenBottles--)`? Or maybe replace `&&` with `||`, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AntonH should make it an answer

Comment: @ScaryWombat I would, but OP hasn't really asked a question, so I can't really say my 'answer' is correct, or give a complete one. For example, I used `&&`, but that would mean that I would never enter the `if` statement that is in the loop.

Comment: Alright sorry I didn't make it clear - I wasn't sure how to make the 'for' have 2 variables as it'd keep giving me an error. Mostly gave me 'not an expression' and was wondering on how to fix it. I think what you gave me has worked though so thanks :D.

Answer (score 0):

The **for** loop contains 3 part separated by **`;`**:

- initialization: where you initialize the loop variable
- Limit for the loop(this should be a condition whose output would be boolean)
- Updating the counter on each iteration

> ```
> for(
>        int xGreenBottles = 11, xyGreenBottles = 10; 
>        (xGreenBottles > 0 && xyGreenBottles > 0); 
>        xGreenBottles --, xyGreenBottles--
>     )
>  {
>             }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to replace your for loop statement with this:

```
for ( int xGreenBottles = 11, xyGreenBottles = 10; xGreenBottles > 0 && xyGreenBottles > 0 ; xGreenBottles--, xyGreenBottles-- )
```

Also please keep in mind that, if I read this correctly, your "if" statement will never evaluate to true since the sequence in which the for loops is evaluated is as follows:

1. Initialize the variables (before the first ;)
2. Check the condition (between the two ;;), exit loop if it fails
3. Execute code block
4. Increment variables (rightmost part of loop, after both ;;)
5. Repeat from #2

This if any of the two variables reaches zero, the loop will interrupt without executing the block.

I am honestly not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve with this code though, perhaps providing some "pseudocode" would help us help you a little bit better... be happy to add to my answer if there is something more specific you are looking for!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used the correct format.

The semicolons are suppose to separate the for loop based on function, you can't mix them up.

Before the first semicolon you initialize the variables:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
```

Before the second semicolon you set the conditions (any expression that returns true or false):

```
a < 10 && b < 10;
```

and in the last section, you manipulate the variables:

```
a++, b++
```

and all together it would be:

```
for (int a = 0, b = 0; a < 10 && b < 10; a++, b++)
```

This is just a formatting example, through which you should be able to easily fix your problem.

Comment: @ScaryWombat changed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (int xGreenBottles = 11, xyGreenBottles = 10; xGreenBottles > 0 && xyGreenBottles > 0; xGreenBottles--, xyGreenBottles--)
{
  if (xGreenBottles == 0 && xyGreenBottles == 0)
  {
    System.out.println(xGreenBottles + " green bottles standing on the wall, " + xGreenBottles + "  green bottles standing on the wall, And if 1 green bottle should accidently fall, there'll be " + xyGreenBottles + " green bottles standing on the wall.");
  }
  else 
  {
    System.out.println("There'll be no green bottles standing on the wall.");
  }
}
```

I believe you meant to do

```
if (xGreenBottles != 0 && xyGreenBottles != 0)
```

I found several questions similar to this, you might considering checking them and evaluating the answers given on those for better understanding of Java for loop syntax.
([Java for loop multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14752536/5325959))